# Using HTML, CSS, javascript how to mange carousel slider in desktop as well as mobile view?https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzW5B.jpg

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I manage using HTML, CSS and Javascript, manage carousel slider manage in desktop and Mobile view as well as?

[image: carousel slider]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a library that supports breakpoints.

The one I prefer is Swiper Slider, you'd just need to change the slidesPerView parameter at different screen width breakpoints, and it also offers touch support.

Comment: Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kishan93/bnd7y93e/) fiddle.
It's what you are asking for, and you can also customize it based on the device width.

And for more info on this plugin go to [this github](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) repository.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

        html, body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background: #eee;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color:#000;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .swiper-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .swiper-slide {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: #fff;
            /* Center slide text vertically */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
         }
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

And this is the js code:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    slidesPerView: 5,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    breakpoints: {
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 40
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 30
        },
        640: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 20
        },
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
        }
    }
});
```